# Why isn't PSReadLine part of my powershell?

Tags: powershell

Why isn't PSReadLine part of the default modules of my powershell? How can I get all the default modules?

```
⨯ idror@TLV-WPJ03  ~  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

But the list of modules I have under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules is just:

- Gist Provider
- PackageManagement
- PowerShellGet

I also have a folder C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules with

- PackageManagement
- PowerShellGet

(I know I have Gist management, so I guess I'm using the 64bit version)

Comment: What does `Get-Module -ListAvailable` return? I guess you don't want all moduls be loadad every time.

Comment: It lists PSReadLine, since I have it under my modules (C:\Users\idror\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules), but not anywhere else (If I try to move the folder from my modules folder, and start PS, I get a lot of errors as it can't find the module)

Comment: Did you read [Post installation tips on gitHub](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine)?

Comment: my question is why is it not a part of the PS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Because PSReadline was available for older versions of PowerShell and frequently and easily installed, not including it by default in WMF packages simplified the installation.

It could also have been considered a feature that would help drive upgrades, though I am skeptical of that reasoning.

Comment: But it is included by default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/core-modules/windows-powershell-5.0?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: In Windows 10, yes, but not in the WMF packages for older versions of Windows like Win8.